# Android NDK: Linking x86 shared library

Tags: android, makefile, android-ndk

I was given a shared library built on Linux x86, let's call it libA.so, and I want to use the function calls provided by this library SDK.

I am having issues building and have a few questions:

1) I will be able to build for x86, but will I be able to build for arm? I believe the answer is no, meaning I cannot run on a Nexus 5 for example.
2) The ndk-build complains of the #include that should be resolved by my LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES. I am not sure why that is. My Android.mk is as follow:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := B
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := B.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := A
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Can someone please help me resolve my Android.mk? I don't understand why it is complaining about my include statement in B.cpp. Please let me know if I can run B in an arm environment, although the SDK I am relying on was built on x86.

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?  Also, can you clarify: you have only a binary version of libA.so compiled for x86, and no source code for libA.so, and you want to have code in your own B.cpp which will call a function from libA.so?

Comment: Yes you are correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your shared library libA.so has been compiled for linux-x86, it will certainly not run on android x86 targets (mainly because it needs to be linked to Bionic C library instead of glibc), and absolutely not on android arm devices.

Then, to solve your second issue, if you can get properly compiled android shared libraries for your android targets, you would include your library this way:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := A
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../libA/prebuilts/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libA.so # path to libA .so file, depending on the target ABI.
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../libA/includes # path to libA headers.
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := B
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := B.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := A
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```